# Multiprocessing and event, type hint issue python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mypy

I have used multiprocessing module to perform a background task.

```
# module_a.py

from multiprocessing import Event
from multiprocessing import Process

class BackgroundWorker(Process):
    """Create a worker background process."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        name: str,
        daemon: bool,
        contents: Any,
        event: Event,
    ) -> None:
        """Initialize the defaults."""
        self.contents: Any = contents
        self._event: Event = event
        super().__init__(name=name, daemon=daemon)

    def run(self) -> None:
        """Run the target function."""
        some code
        
        if self._event.wait(0.4):
        
        some code
        
        if self._event.is_set():
            break
            
       some code
```

```
# module_b.py

from multiprocessing import Event

event: Event = Event()

def cancel_task():
    event.set()
```

Following are the errors on running `mypy`

```
error: Variable "multiprocessing.Event" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
error: Variable "multiprocessing.Event" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases
error: Event? has no attribute "is_set"  [attr-defined]
error: Event? has no attribute "wait"  [attr-defined]
```

Please suggest.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Event` is a function (not a class) due to implementation of contexts. use: `from multiprocessing.synchronize import Event as EventClass` for hinting the base class of `Event`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Aaron, the new changes as below

```
# module_a.py

from multiprocessing.synchronize import Event as EventClass

replace Event with EventClass
for eg, 
self._event: EventClass = event
```

```
# module_b.py

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.synchronize import Event as EventClass

event: EventClass = multiprocessing.Event()

def cancel_task():
    event.set()
```

Comment: I like `from multiprocessing.synchronize import Event as SyncEvent` a little better